# 2D list to np.ndarray of ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

### I have a 2D list like this

```
import numpy as np
data=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

I want to turn this to np.ndarray.

I don't want to get this:

```
np.array(data).shape
#(3,2)
```

### my expected is like this

```
result=np.array(np.array([1,2]),np.array([2,3]),np.array([3,4]))

result.dtype
result.shape
#np.ndarry
#(3,)
result[i].shape
result[i].dtype
#(2,)
#np.ndarry
```

what should i do this a lot

Comment: This seems like a strange thing to want. What problem are you trying to solve this way?

Comment: make a (3,) object dtype array, and assign this list to it.

Answer (score 3):

AS @hpaulj suggested in comments
You can create first [`empty`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) array of `object` type and then assign list to it like

```
data = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
result = np.empty(shape=len(data), dtype=object)

result[:] = [np.array(i) for i in data]
result
array([array([1, 2]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 4])], dtype=object)

result.shape
(3,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the list into an ndarray and then flattening it

`np.array(data).flatten()`

You can also specify order parameter in flatten to flatten in row-major ('C') or column-major ('F') order